# Custom Pie chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, pie-chart, flutter-charts

I am trying to build a pie chart like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKzIP.png) I have tried library but I am unable to achieve this type of chart. Is there any way to build a chart like this in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [syncfusion_flutter_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts)  to achieve this feature.and don't forgot change cornerStyle as `cornerStyle: CornerStyle.endCurve`

sample link: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/circular-charts/chart-types/doughnut/rounded-corners

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildRoundedDoughnutChart();
  }

  /// Returns the circular charts with rounded corner doughnut series.
  SfCircularChart _buildRoundedDoughnutChart() {
    return SfCircularChart(
      legend: Legend(
          isVisible: !isCardView, overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap),
      title: ChartTitle(text: isCardView ? '' : 'Software development cycle'),
      series: _getRoundedDoughnutSeries(),
    );
  }

  /// Returns rounded corner doughunut series.
  List<DoughnutSeries<ChartSampleData, String>> _getRoundedDoughnutSeries() {
    return <DoughnutSeries<ChartSampleData, String>>[
      DoughnutSeries<ChartSampleData, String>(
        dataSource: <ChartSampleData>[
          ChartSampleData(x: 'Planning', y: 10),
          ChartSampleData(x: 'Analysis', y: 10),
          ChartSampleData(x: 'Design', y: 10),
          ChartSampleData(x: 'Development', y: 10),
          ChartSampleData(x: 'Testing & Integration', y: 10),
          ChartSampleData(x: 'Maintainance', y: 10)
        ],
        animationDuration: 0,
        cornerStyle: CornerStyle.endCurve,
        radius: '80%',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.x as String,
        yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.y,
      ),
    ];
  }
```

Comment: is it free to use?

Comment: yes, it's free package